# How to update ReactJS's `create-react-app`?

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

The [ReactJS docs stated](https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html) we can use

```
npx create-react-app my-app
```

to create a React app.  But how do we update the `create-react-app`?  Is there a general rule if it is something started by `npx`?  I keep on clicking on some links and reached the site https://create-react-app.dev/ and it has a line:

```
npm install react-scripts@latest
```

but I wonder if I run it, it is not `-g` (global), so will it let us create a React app in any folder?  Also when I ran it, it gave:

```
found 6289 vulnerabilities (4974 low, 306 moderate, 1004 high, 5 critical)
```

so there seems to be something that needs to be done extra.

Answer (score 18):

If it's an existing app, usually updating `package.json` to the latest version manually works well (I haven't had any issues with it, but it may break, depending on how old your project is).

`npx` will use the latest version, provided you didn't have a global one installed. If so, uninstall first:

```
npm uninstall -g create-react-app
```

Then run:

```
npx create-react-app my-app
```

If the version you see in the package is the latest (right now it's 3.4.0) it means you did get the latest one. It may be another package throwing the warnings?

Comment: is it true I can use `npm list -g create-react-app` to see if any global one is installed?

Comment: Yes, do you see it? If so, remove it 

Comment: I see... I feel like I have to take a class in `npm`

Comment: I got 
`C:\Users\ACER\AppData\Roaming\npm
└── (empty)`
when I run `npm list -g create-react-app` in a new project with `npx create-react-app myApp` then I suppose is not globaly installed but I still have vulnerabilities when I try to install dependencies (like sass). Any Idea ?

Answer (score 17):

`npx` is a package runner, from the [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npx):

> Executes  either from a local node_modules/.bin, or from a central cache, installing any packages needed in order for  to run.
>
> By default, npx will check whether  exists in $PATH, or in the local project binaries, and execute that. If  is not found, it will be installed prior to execution.

So unless you have installed `create-react-app` globally (your shouldn't), it will download the latest and use it. On the second command you found:

```
npm install react-scripts@latest
```

This is not for updating create-react-app CLI, but the `react-scripts` version used in the `react-app` itself. `react-scripts` is the package that bundles the `babel`, `webpack` and all the configuration in your react application.

From the [docs](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/updating-to-new-releases/):

> create-react-app is a global command-line utility that you use to create new projects.
>
> react-scripts is a development dependency in the generated projects (including this one).

Comment: so on https://create-react-app.dev/ it says "Updating your build tooling is typically a daunting and time-consuming task. When new versions of Create React App are released, you can upgrade using a single command `npm install react-scripts@latest`" and it is a bit misleading?

Comment: Nope! you can upgrade using a single command. that would be `npm install react-scripts@latest`

Comment: I thought you mean `npx create-react-app my-app` will use the latest `create-react-app` so why do we still use `npm install react-scripts@latest`?

Comment: the first is for upgrading the global command line tool, the second is for upgrading the tools in your existing react project

Answer (score 16):

ERR:You are running `create-react-app` 4.0.1, which is behind the latest release (4.0.3).

**npm install -g create-react-app**

This updates it to latest version globally. And then you can run 'npx create-react-app appname'

Comment: perfect! ty. For some reason, I was unable to uninstall it globally. I have no reason to have create-react-app installed globally as far as I know. But it seems stuck on being an old version.

Comment: This is the only thing that worked for me. The others didn't.

Comment: This is the only thing that worked for me as well. Doing a global uninstall followed by the npx create-react-app resulted in the errors cited above. It would be nice of the docs made sense.

Comment: same (was unable to uninstall it globally), only way I could fix mine. In case anyone is wondering:
$ npm list -g create-react-app
/home/my.domain/my-name/.nvm/versions/node/v16.14.0/lib
└── (empty)

Answer (score 3):

`npx` is a CLI tool whose purpose is to make it easy to install and manage dependencies hosted in the npm registry or any locally installed packages. It has ability to execute a package that wasn’t previously been installed.

> NPX will always execute the latest available version in the NPM registry unless the version is specified.

If you have already installed `create-react-app` globally, then you can solve the problem by first trying to uninstall the npm globally, update the npm and then clear the cache(**Note:** It's important to clear the cache).

The command is as below:

```
sudo npm uninstall -g create-react-app && sudo npm i -g npm@latest && sudo npm cache clean -f
```

Please refer the [docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/configuring-npm/folders#cache) for clearing the cache.

> In latest releases, `create-react-app` does not support global installations.

Answer (score -1):

Using

> npx create-react-app@latest project-name

worked for me.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).